# is there an API for the Youtube Subscription button?

Tags: button, youtube, youtube-api, subscription

Ive been trying to find a code same with the google +, facebook like, twitter follow, code which is given by their respective developers for a easy embedding for newbies like me...

ive been searching alot for it but all that shows is that their is a iframed one and a youtube api which i dont really know how to use (maybe for professional developers only)

what i want to do is like the one they are showing with any vids

which also have a "red Subscription button and the Subscription count" of it like any social plugins given above...

im sorry for trying to find help is just that i dont know how to code since i dont know much of advance coding.. Thank you for your consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would seem that the only and best way to do it is through the data api. The specific page you want for subscription button is:

[subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions)

Try using the JSON example they give on that page and swap in your details.

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer user2609718 glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Code for "Youtube Subscribe Button with Subscription Count" JSON to PHP

```
<?php 
    /* Getting Subscription count from the user */
    function getYouTubeSubscriberCount($user)
    {
        $data = file_get_contents(sprintf('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s', $user));
        $matches = array();
        preg_match("~subscriberCount='(?<count>\d+)'~", $data, $matches);
        return isset($matches['count']) ? $matches['count'] : 0 ;
    }
    echo getYouTubeSubscriberCount('Username/ChannelName'); #181218
    ?>

/* Link to Subscription Confirmation to another tab */
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=Username/ChannelName" target="_tab"><img src="images/youtube.png" height="22" width="90"/></a> </td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a simple API for the Youtube subscribe button:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/